# 1004 error: Application-Defined Object-Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a 1004 error but I am not sure why?

```
Sub my_script()

Sheets("mysheet").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Rows(6)).Font.Color = vbWhite

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to `Select` the worksheet in order to modify row 6 font's color.

Also, `Range(Rows(6))` is not valid, use `Rows(6)`.

```
Sub my_script()

Sheets("mysheet").Rows(6).Font.Color = vbWhite

End Sub
```